# jQuery doesn't work. Why?

Tags: jquery

You can find the website I am building at [here](http://kerstlichtshow.hostingsiteforfree.com/home.html).

There is a **menu.js** with some jQuery code. It should color the parts of the menu (`<li>`) when the mouse is hovered over that part of the menu (this). But it appears not to work. I linked the file that is necessary for jQuery (**jQuery.min.js**) to my **home.php** and I did the same with the **jquery.animate-colors.js**, but it won't work. Does anybody know why?

PS: if you look at the **style.css** and remove the /* and */ around the **ul#avmenu a:hover{}** part, you will see what should happen, but I want to use jQuery because I want a smooth animation.

Comment: It's not working because you're including `jquery.animate-colors.js` *before* the jQuery library and causing a Javascript error/exception.

Answer (score 1):

that is beacuse **you are loading animate.js first and jquery second**.. and since animate.js depends on jquery.. your error says jQuery is not defined...**load jquery.js first**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script src="jquery.animate-colors.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery code change `('this')` to `(this)` without quotes.

Comment: Did that but there seems to be at least one other problem. I put the link to menu.js inside commentbracets and putted the code in the head, so you can look there now.

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the animate-colors js file before you're loading jquery, thus the animate colors can't access Jquery functions...

So, instead of:

```
<script src="jquery.animate-colors.js">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
```

make it like this:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"> 
<script src="jquery.animate-colors.js">
```

You can debug that btw by looking at the Console tab in Firebug. When reloading the page, you can see a `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` is been given.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! But there is another problem now. One of the li s in the menu has an **class="active"** atribute. In my css was a line of code which said that the one with the class active a different color had (no matter if it is a hover). Right now, my jQuery code takes over everything with **ul#avmenu a**, so the one with **class="active"** also reacts on a mouseover and is never the color it should be, not on mouseover and not without it. How do I exclude the **ul#avmenu a.active** at my jQuery (menu.js)?